# How to use ansible 'expect' module for multiple different responses?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

Here I am trying to test my bash script where it is prompting four times.

```
#!/bin/bash
date >/opt/prompt.txt
read -p "enter one: " one
echo $one
echo $one >>/opt/prompt.txt
read -p "enter two: " two
echo $two
echo $two >>/opt/prompt.txt
read -p "enter three: " three
echo $three
echo $three >>/opt/prompt.txt
read -p "enter password: " password
echo $password
echo $password >>/opt/prompt.txt
```

for this script I wrote the code below, and it is working fine

```
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Test Script
    expect:
      command: sc.sh
      responses:
        enter one: 'one'
        enter two: 'two'
        enter three: 'three'
        enter password: 'pass'
      echo: yes
```

But if I am doing the same for `mysql_secure_installation` command it not working

```
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  tasks:
  - name: mysql_secure_installation Command Test
    expect:
      command: mysql_secure_installation
      responses:
        'Enter current password for root (enter for none):': "\n"
        'Set root password? [Y/n]:': 'y'
        'New password:': '123456'
        'Re-enter new password:': '123456'
        'Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]:': 'y'
        'Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n]:': 'y'
        'Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n]:': 'y'
        'Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n]:': 'y'

      echo: yes
```

and its trackback is here:

```
PLAY [S1] **********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [S1]

TASK [mysql_secure_installation Command Test] **********************************
fatal: [S1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mysql_secure_installation", "delta": "0:00:30.139266", "end": "2016-07-15 15:36:32.549415", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-07-15 15:36:02.410149", "stdout": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nNOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MySQL\r\n      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!\r\n\r\n\r\nIn order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current\r\npassword for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and\r\nyou haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,\r\nso you should just press enter here.\r\n\r\nEnter current password for root (enter for none): ", "stdout_lines": ["", "", "", "", "NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MySQL", "      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!", "", "", "In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current", "password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and", "you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,", "so you should just press enter here.", "", "Enter current password for root (enter for none): "]}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/jackson/AnsibleWorkSpace/AnsibleTest/example1.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
S1                         : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I have also tried blank `''` instead of `"\n"` for the first answer but it is not working either. I also visited Ansible [`expect`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) doc but they show only very simple example and explanation. I am also trying regex match for multiple different responses but it is also not working.
Please do not recommend me to use mysql module of Ansible, because here my purpose is to learn this module for future use.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The reason is that the questions are interpreted as regexps. Hence you must escape characters with a special meaning in regular expressions, such as -()[]\?*. et cetara.

Hence:

```
'Enter current password for root (enter for none):'
```

should instead be:

```
'Enter current password for root \(enter for none\):'
```

Good luck!