# How to use expect in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a playbook for installation of tableau server. but there is a part where it needs a response.

Here is my code:

```
- name: Apply Changes
  expect:
    command: /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.10500.19.0313.1245/tsm pending-changes apply -u ansible -p ansible
    responses:
      'This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?(y/n):': 'y'
    timeout: 600
    echo: yes
  tags:
    - start
```

but I have an error

```
atal: [tableau3.server.com]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.10500.19.0313.1245/tsm pending-changes apply -u ansible -p ansible", 
    "delta": "0:10:00.223831", 
    "end": "2019-05-05 21:16:46.914799", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null, 
            "command": "/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.10500.19.0313.1245/tsm pending-changes apply -u ansible -p ansible", 
            "creates": null, 
            "echo": true, 
            "removes": null, 
            "responses": {
                "This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?(y/n):": "y"
            }, 
            "timeout": 600
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 129, 
    "start": "2019-05-05 21:06:46.690968", 
    "stdout": "This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?\r\n(y/n): ", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?", 
        "(y/n): "
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393343/how-to-use-ansible-expect-module-for-multiple-different-responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command responds with 2 lines

```
stdout_lines": [
    "This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?", 
    "(y/n): "
```

, but the item in *responses* expects only 1 line.

```
responses:
  'This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?(y/n):': 'y'
```

Hence, no item in *responses* fits and the module fails.

The responses are string/regex. Try

```
responses:
  y/n: 'y'
```

[Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#notes) says:

> The expect module is designed for simple scenarios. For more complex needs, consider the use of expect code with the shell or script modules. (An example is part of the shell module documentation)